# Coloring 9 squares in a 9x9 grid

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

In a 9 x 9 grid, how many ways can you color 9 boxes red such that

1. No two red squares touch either adjacently or diagonally.
2. there is exactly one red square in each row, and there is exactly one red square in
   each column

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: If you keep on ignoring the advice in [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), your questions will keep getting closed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a difficult combinatorial problem.

In https://oeis.org/A002464 you will find a list of the number of ways, $A(n)$, for $n\times n$ boards.

The answer given there for $A(9)$ is $47622$.

There is also a recurrence relation for these numbers.

$$A(n)=(n+1)A(n-1)-(n-2)A(n-2)-(n-5)A(n-3)+(n-3)A(n-4).$$